# Time Elapsed In Hours Between Multiple Dates In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to find a formula that works out the business hours between two dates in excel.

The business hours start at 09:00 and end at 17:00 and do not include weekends.

The spreadsheet is currently laid out in the following way;

```
A1: Start Time       -       B1: End Time   -       C1: Total Business hours
A2: 2016-01-04 10:31:17   -  B2: 2016-01-06 10:02:14
```

Is there a formula I can use that will calculate the difference in time (business hours) and display it in C2?

Comment: how do you want to manage minutes? what is the expected result in your example?

Comment: I'm working on it at the moment, but it is not easy to do what you are asking

Comment: Expected result in the example is 15 hours 31 mins (don't worry about the seconds). If you can get close it would be great!

Comment: It is for a helpdesk ticket resolution time, so the answer will display how long the ticket has been open in the system. But we require the time to only include business working hours

Comment: Will these examples include start and end dates that are not in the same year?

Comment: No they will always be in the same year as I will run reports from Jan to Dec. But they will be in different months

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer, but `NETWORKDAYS` can be very useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dates are in the same year and neglecting a small round off error I've found a viable solution:

I'll first explain it and then add the formula below.

I've split the solution in multiple instances if's

**IF 1: DATES IN SAME WEEK**

```
IF(WEEKNUMBER(A2)=WEEKNUMBER(B2);
```

**IF 1.1: DATES ON SAME DAY**

```
IF(DAY(A2)=DAY(B2));
```

Take the hours of end date minus hours of start date = result

```
(B2-A2)*24;
```

**IF 1.2: DATES NOT ON SAME DAY**

Take the day of the end date minus the day of the begin date (=the days between both dates) and multiply by 8 (=17-9) and add the difference in hours. The MOD function is used to cut off the days of the dates and only remain with the time.

```
(DAY(B2)-DAY(A2))*(17-9)+(MOD(B2,1)-MOD(A2,1))*24);
```

**IF 2: DATES NOT IN SAME WEEK**

I calculate the number of hours of the weeks in between, then I add the hours of the start date to the end of the start week (luckily the year started on a friday so I could just do weeknumber(startdate)*7 and finally I add the number of hours from the start of the week to the end date.

```
(WEEKNUMBER(B2)-WEEKNUMMER(A2)-1)*5*(17-9)+(WEEKNUMBER(A2)*7-QUOTIENT(A2;1))*(17-9)+17+(QUOTIENT(B2;1)-(WEEKNUMBER(B2)*7-4))*(17-9)+(MOD(B2;1)-MOD(A2;1))*24-9)
```

At the end, you just need to put all these pieces of code together and you can calculate the business hours between dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another formula that uses the `NETWORKDAYS` function which would allow you specify Holidays or, if you have a later version of Excel, you could substitute `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` to specify which days are your weekend.

- Count 8 hours for every working day
- Subtract the time between 9AM and the actual start_time
- Subtract the time between the actual end_time and 5PM on that date:

---

```
=NETWORKDAYS([@[Start Time]],[@[End Time]])*8/24-
([@[Start Time]]-(INT([@[Start Time]])+9/24))-
(INT([@[End Time]])+17/24-[@[End Time]])
```

Since we adjust to represent the time as fractions of a day, the results will be in Excel date/time format and can be formatted to display seconds, if you wish.

[image]