# Excel Formula to work out time differences from start to finish

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need an Excel formula to work out time;
basically something like the following:

```
 Start Time   Start Date     End Time   End Date        Total Time
 08:00        26-Dec-2017    09:00      27-Dec-2017     1 day 1 hour (or 25 hours)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Also, there are several questions that exist on this site answering exactly that question so as evidence of no research....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time Elapsed In Hours Between Multiple Dates In Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1106416/time-elapsed-in-hours-between-multiple-dates-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just calculate the difference between two cells (eg `B1 - A1`) and use custom formatting ('`h`' for hours or '`h:mm`' for hours and minutes).

See also [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6) for a more detailed explanation.